# Accidently launched an iOS app on ipad and iphone

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, ipad

Im not sure if i'm posting this in correct area and haven't seen anyone recently with the same question.

I launched a iOS app on the iOS app store and when i did i also launched it into the iPad as well. As of now is there any way to remove it from iPad without completely deleting it from app store and losing my app name?

And if there is no way is there any way to make my app behave like its on a iphone at all time without having to adjust each single view to work on the iPad as well?

Any where in xCode settings that makes it just behave like iPhone on an iPad? I have a custom camera and lots of 9 x 16 views that is difficult to account for on ipad.

Thank You!

Comment: If you have released your app as universal (Supporting both iPhone and iPad natively) then you cannot make it iPhone only.  You can only increase device support, not decrease it

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this.  Apple says that you cannot take away supporting a specific device type once you do it.

> Developers who wish to issue updates, but remove device support, have
> three choices:
>
> - Fix their app so that it can work on the devices they originally set out to support.
> - Target a newer version of iOS that requires a newer device.
> - Remove their app from the store, and upload the new app with a different bundle ID.

Apple's recommendation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1623/_index.html) is to add the device support back, or remove the app from the store and upload it back as a new bundle id (not ideal). Option 2 above really doesn't apply to what you are trying to do.

Comment: can you ADD the support for IPad later?